# How can I add a column to a DataFrame which groups rows in chunks of N? Like NTILE, but with a fixed bucket size

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have a DataFrame like:

```
+------------+-----------+-----+
|        feed|artist     |count|
+------------+-----------+-----+
|           y| Kanye West|    9|
|           y|  Radiohead|    6|
|           y|     Zero 7|    3|
|           y| Puts Marie|    1|
|        gwas|       Drax|    7|
|        gwas|    Calibre|    4|
|        gwas| Aphex Twin|    1|
|        gwas|      Jay Z|    1|
|           x|   DJ Krush|    2|
|           x|  Titeknots|    1|
+------------+-----------+-----+
```

I want to add a new column which chunks the rows into buckets of `N` rows for each partition (`feed`).

It seems like the inverse of NTILE to me. NTILE lets you choose the # of buckets but I want to choose the bucket-size instead.

Here's the desired result. Notice how each `feed` is chunked into groups of `N = 2`, including the `x` feed which has just one chunk of `2` rows. (**Edit:** each partition is ordered by `count`, so group `1` in each partition will be the rows with the highest value for `count`)

```
+------------+-----------+-----+-----+
|        feed|artist     |count|group|
+------------+-----------+-----+-----+
|           y| Kanye West|    1|    9|
|           y|  Radiohead|    1|    6|
|           y|     Zero 7|    1|    3|
|           y| Puts Marie|    1|    1|
|        gwas|       Drax|    7|    7|
|        gwas|    Calibre|    1|    4|
|        gwas| Aphex Twin|    1|    1|
|        gwas|      Jay Z|    8|    1|
|           x|   DJ Krush|    2|    2|
|           x|  Titeknots|    1|    1|
+------------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

As a bonus, I would like each bucket to be a different size. E.g. `List(2, 2, 4, 10, 10, -1)` would mean that the first bucket has `2` rows, the second has `2` rows, the third has `4` rows, etc., and the final bucket (`-1`) contains the remainder.

**EDIT**

(Another useful variation)

While implementing the answers, I realized that there's another variation which I would prefer:

Add a column to a DataFrame which chunks its rows into groups of N, without knowing the size of the DataFrame.

Example:

If `N = 100` and the DataFrame has `800` rows, it chunk it into `8` buckets of 100. If the DataFrame has `950` rows, it will chunk it into `9` buckets of 100, and `1` bucket of 50. It should **not** require a scan/call to `.count()`.

The example DataFrames are analogous to the ones above.

(meta: should I make a new question for this variation? I feel like "NTILE with a fixed bucket size" is a more elegant problem and probably more common than my original use-case)

Comment: can you explain how the `group` should be calculated? Why is `Kanye West` in group 1 but `Zero 7` in group 2?

Comment: Good question, I forgot to make that clear. Each partition will be ordered by `count`, and that will be used to calculate groups. So the first 2 rows will be group `1`, the next 2 rows group `2`, etc.. I want to use this to chunk my DataFrame into groups of ~100 and then save it using `df.save.partitionBy('group`).csv('...')` to get an output folder structure like `2020/01/16/group=1/blah.csv`. Anyway, I'll update the OP to cover that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this can be handled by using an SQL expression:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{expr,row_number,desc}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// set up WindowSpec
val w1 = Window.partitionBy("feed").orderBy(desc("count"))

val L = List(2, 2, 4, 10, 10, -1)

// dynamically create SQL expression from the List `L` to map row_number into group-id
var sql_expr = "CASE"
var running_total = 0
for(i <- 1 to L.size) {
  running_total += L(i-1)
  sql_expr += (if(L(i-1) > 0) s" WHEN rn <= $running_total THEN $i " else s" ELSE $i END")
}
println(sql_expr)
//CASE  WHEN rn <= 2 THEN 1  WHEN rn <= 4 THEN 2  WHEN rn <= 8 THEN 3  WHEN rn <= 18 THEN 4  WHEN rn <= 28 THEN 5  ELSE 6 END 

val df_new = df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w1)).withColumn("group", expr(sql_expr)).drop("rn")
df_new.show
+----+----------+-----+-----+
|feed|    artist|count|group|
+----+----------+-----+-----+
|gwas|      Drax|    7|    1|
|gwas|   Calibre|    4|    1|
|gwas|Aphex Twin|    1|    2|
|gwas|     Jay Z|    1|    2|
|   x|  DJ Krush|    2|    1|
|   x| Titeknots|    1|    1|
|   y|Kanye West|    9|    1|
|   y| Radiohead|    6|    1|
|   y|    Zero 7|    3|    2|
|   y|Puts Marie|    1|    2|
+----+----------+-----+-----+
```

For a fixed N, just cast `(row_number-1)/N + 1` to int:

```
val N = 2
val df_new = df.withColumn("group", ((row_number().over(w1)-1)/N+1).cast("int"))
```

Comment: brilliant once more!

Comment: This is my preferred answer, SQL is easy to understand and it doesn't require a UDF or intermediate DataFrame to join on. I'm accepting this answer but I've edited the OP to include another variation that I would find useful- I would appreciate if you could take a look! Thanks!

Comment: @RoryByrne, the variation you added should be the same as a fixed N mentioned at the end of my post, just set `N = 100` and calculate `(row_number-1)/N + 1` and then cast the result to integer. no need SQL expression.

Answer (score 1):

This could work :

```
val bucketDef =  List(2, 2, 4, 10, 10)

val bucketRunsum = bucketDef.scanLeft(1)( _ + _) // calc running sum

// maps a row-number to a bucket
val indexBucketMapping = bucketRunsum.zip(bucketRunsum.tail)
  .zipWithIndex
  .map{case ((start,end),index) => ((start,end),index+1)} // make index start at 1

// gives List(((1,3),1), ((3,5),2), ((5,9),3), ((9,19),4), ((19,29),5))

// udf to assign a bucket to a given row-number
val calcBucket = udf((rnb:Long) => indexBucketMapping
  .find{case ((start,end),_) => start<=rnb && rnb < end}
  .map(_._2) // get index
  .getOrElse(indexBucketMapping.last._2+1) // is in last bucket
)

df
  .withColumn("group",calcBucket(row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"feed").orderBy($"count"))))
```

alternatively (without UDF), construct a DataFrame which maps a row-number to a bucket and then join

```
val bucketSizeDef =List(2, 2, 4, 10, 10)
val bucketDef =  (1 +: bucketSizeDef).zipWithIndex.map{case (bs,index) => (bs,index+1)}
    .toDF("bucketSize","group")
    .withColumn("i",sum($"bucketSize").over(Window.orderBy($"group")))
    .withColumn("i_to",coalesce(lead($"i",1).over(Window.orderBy($"group")),lit(Long.MaxValue)))
    .drop($"bucketSize")

bucketDef.show()
```

gives:

```
+-----+---+-------------------+
|group|  i|               i_to|
+-----+---+-------------------+
|    1|  1|                  3|
|    2|  3|                  5|
|    3|  5|                  9|
|    4|  9|                 19|
|    5| 19|                 29|
|    6| 29|9223372036854775807|
+-----+---+-------------------+
```

then join to df:

```
df
  .withColumn("rnb",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"feed").orderBy($"count")))
  .join(broadcast(bucketDef),$"rnb">= $"i" and $"rnb"< $"i_to")
  .drop("rnb","i","i_to")
```

Comment: Nice solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these solutions tomorrow. Will they scale well to large datasets? Also, I'm surprised that the solutions are so complex, I was expecting something a lot simpler!

Comment: I chose the other answer because it's simpler and SQL based so less Spark API knowledge is necessary. I've edited the OP to include another variation that I would find useful, but I suspect the SQL approach won't be able to achieve it so maybe this answer can be extended to achieve it? I'd like if you could take a look!